Mapping wifi signal strength to 5-bar indicator
I want to create an indicator of WiFi signal strength that displays 5 bars based on the RSSI level in decibels.
However, I am seeing conflicting (albeit roughly similar) interpretations of RSSI levels:
From https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/understanding-rssi/:



Level
Quality




-30
"Amazing"


-67
"Very Good"


-70
"Okay"


-80
"Not Good"


-90
"Unusable"



From https://www.netspotapp.com/wifi-signal-strength/what-is-rssi-level.html:



Level
Quality




-50
"Excellent"


-60
"Very Good"


-70
"Good"


-80
"Low"


-90
"Very Low"



From some paper about IoT:

Etc.

I am not sure which one would lead to the best results.
My question is, what decibel ranges should I assign to each bar?

Can you provide more details regarding the purpose and context of this wifi indicator? Why would a user need it in your app? Or are you building the OS of a device?

@Morco I'm building a UI on a screen on a custom device where you can select a wifi network for it to connect to, and I want to display the signal strength of each network graphically in a familiar manner. I'm also going to use the same indicator to display the signal strength of the currently connected wifi network up in the corner of the screen. Basically the same way the indicators are used on say an Android phone.

From what I see, they have similar standards, different only for the top values.

Under -70 means decent
Under -80 means bad
Under -90 means very bad

Value -30 seems to be the maximum, so you have to translate the range -70 to -30 into two more bars. You could choose -50, the middle, for example.
From a UX point of view, since the user doesn't know exactly what those values actually mean and since the wifi signals will not corelate directly to app performance or download speed, then your wifi meter becomes just a simple convention in your app.
As a rule of thumb, low quality values are more similar to each other than high quality values. In other words, if something is bad, it doesn't matter if it's "less bad" or "more bad", because it's still bad, so it's something to be avoided anyway.
But when it comes to something being good, that's when the user starts to care and distinguish between good and very good. If your meter says that a service is "very good", then the user will have high expectations and will be more frustrated if those expectations are not met accordingly.
Therefore, when your indicator shows the maximum wifi bars, then you should be certain that the signal is actually very good for most use cases. For a signal with values from -70 to -30, I would reserve the maximum bars for something very close to -30 (like -50, or even -40), even though it might rarely be achieved. In most situations, your indicator would show only 4 bars and rarely 5 bars, even for very good signals.
It's better to under promise and over deliver, than to betray your user's expectations.
